# How to convert matterport mask_rcnn keras(.h5) model to coreml model(.mlmodel) using coremltools

Tags: python, coreml, coremltools

I trained a model using matterport maskrcnn. I already had .h5 model file but i am not able to convert it to .mlmodel.  As there are many custom layers involved. I already tried whatever I am able to find on google regarding the same. I also tried https://github.com/edouardlp/Mask-RCNN-CoreML for conversion. So far no success.

Does anybody able to did the conversion so far successfully, if yes can you share the codebase or tutorial for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to convert using the same github repo mentioned in the question. But you can't debug the code in Xcode as maskrcnn is to memory heavy. Its better to use another architecture like deeplab.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a github project https://github.com/edouardlp/Mask-RCNN-CoreML/releases/tag/0.2 with a MaskRCNN.ml model.

Note:  You have to copy the models into the project to get it to compile.